# Your own caffe model from first pricinples

Tags: python, computer-vision, caffe

I am new to caffe. I've gotten so far that I've installed caffe, pycaffe and matcaffe and looked at some tutorials.

I'd like to build my own (lm)db file to use to train a model.

As far as I can tell, all the tutorials at caffe.berkeleyvision.com use a set of preprocessed binary files when they create their lmdb files.

I'd like to start from basics: Say that I have a small set of images in just the right format (jpeg, tiff, whatever it happens to be). In this example that's all I've got. However the number of images is small so I could, in this hypothetical scenario, assign every picture a label myself, manually. Not good if you are actually going to train a model, if one is out to understand the process of creating a lmdb file, however - gold!

Feel free to substitute lmdb for h5py or whatever suits the situation the best.

**How would I go about creating a databasde from a set of images alone?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with hand labeling, you can create a text document that has a line for each image with the file name/location along with the label, e.g.

```
img1.jpg 0
img2.jpg 1
img3.jpb 3
img4.jpg 0
[...]
```

Then, either use an `ImageData` layer or convert it to an lmdb or leveldb with the `convert_imageset` tool that comes with caffe.